# JSSOR - exporting code

Tags: jssor

I am using website builder for a site this week and you cant ftp anything when using that.  I am doing a logo slider from JSSOR and I do not know which code export to use.  I cant upload the images folder, I have to use a direct code link.  Anybody know what option I need to use for exporting code?

Thank you!

Comment: If your website builder doesn't enable you to insert html code, you can use nothing else but components of your website builder.

Comment: Or you can use absolute url of your image refers to any website, you can export copy/paste code to insert it into your page with your website builder.